# Find all the functions that verifies a relation.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals

### **Problem**

Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of strictly positive numbers with $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$.

Find all the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that have primitives and satisfy the following relation:

$2f(x)=f(x+a_n) + f(x-a_n)$, for every $x∈\mathbb{R}$ and $n∈\mathbb{N}$

### **Attempt**

First, as the functions needs to have primitives using indefinite integrals I transformed the initial relation and obtained the new one identical to the first one except for the fact is it $F$ instead of $f$.

(I set the constant of integration all to $0$ as I don't see any proper use to solve the problem.)

$2f(x)=f(x+a_n) + f(x-a_n)$

$2F(x)=F(x+a_n) + F(x-a_n)$

My thesis is that the only function that respect the relations are $f(x) = ax+b$ for every $a,b∈\mathbb{R}$, but I cannot manage to prove this.

I also thought about integrating using definite integral and using another function $g(x)$ to simplify the problem, but I cannot see any light of hope as $f$ is not differentiable.

Any hints or ideas are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t:[0,a_0]\to\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function with the property that $t(a_n)=f(x)-f(x-a_n)$.

The equality can be written as $f(x)-f(x-a_n)=f(x+a_n)-f(x)=t(a_n)$.

Integrating, you have $F(x+a_n)-F(x)-F(a_n)=xt(a_n)$. We can divide by $a_n$, as it is greater than $0$. You'll have $(F(x+a_n)-F(x))/a_n=(F(a_n)+xt(a_n))/a_n$, and when you do the limit you have $f(x)=f(0)+t'(a_n)x$.

Therefore, $f(x)=ax+b$, for any $a,b$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: From this integrating $f(x)−f(x−a_n)=f(x+a_n)−f(x)=t(a_n)$ and then you get $F(x+a_n)−F(x)−F(a_n)=xt(a_n)$, doesn't this mean that F(0)=0? If so, can you tell me how you got it?Or how did you integrate that honestly I don't understand where that F(a_n) came from:)?

Comment: Or how can you deduce that t is a differentiable function if it is defined on many isolated points?